# Android: Switching noise in SoundBoard

Tags: android, noise, ogg

I am developing a Soundboard application. I use MediaPlayer to Play Ogg sound files. Now when I switch from one sound to another sound, I get a noise similar to the ones heard while switching radio stations. I do not want this noise. How to eliminate it? Any Ideas? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. It was because of the **conversion** of the files from **mp3** to **ogg**. MP3 files were of higher bitrate and when converted to ogg ended up in the loss of quality which resulted in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly answer but try adjusting the volume level to the lowest possible before making the switch, then resetting back to the user's original level when completed - sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your idea Cirrus. But it is very difficult to mute the volume before the switch occurs and restore the volume. It will hit the performance of my application.

Comment: Yea, I know.  That's why my answer came with an apology.  Do me a favor, though, and post back whatever you find on this (if no good answer is provided by someone else, that is) ... I'm curious about this and would like to know what the real solution is.  Thanks Vivek.

Comment: Sure Cirrus. I appreciate it.